# hcitool scan does not find my bluetooth device

Tags: command-line, bluetooth

I have a small device that has a bluetooth chip. I can see it through the GUI System Settings > Bluetooth, when adding and discovering a new bluetooth device nearby, but every time I try this command hcitool scan.,no devices can be found.

```
y@MyPC:~$ sudo hcitool scan
Scanning ...
y@MyPC:~$
```

Is the Bluetooth GUI using a different tool than hcitool to scan for bluetooth devices?

Answer (score 1):

`man hcitool` lists the following option:

```
-i <hciX>
       The command is applied to device hciX , which must be the name of an
       installed Bluetooth device. If not specified, the command will be sent
       to the first available Bluetooth device.
```

I suspect your “small device” bluetooth chip is *not* the default `hci0`, so `hcitool` doesn't send commands to it unless you say so. To display available local devices, run:

```
hcitool dev
```

This will show a list of devices with their device names. Pick the one you want and execute e.g.

```
hcitool -i hci1 scan
```